# unable to upload 5 pictures at once using formData array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a mechanism for uploading 5 pictures at once on change of the files input.
for some reason I am unable to upload 5 pictures in one try, 4 pictures are fine, and 5 pictures not at the same try works too, but 5 at once ... .blah :(

this is my code, I guess I have a stupid mistake, help me please :(
when i debug it the pictures[] array i send if null, if i upload 4 pictures it's filled.

```
var uploaded_images = 0;
$('#post-upload-pictures').change(function(){
    var formData = new FormData(), pictures = this.files, i;
    uploaded_images = uploaded_images + pictures.length;
    if (pictures.length > 5 || uploaded_images > 5){
        uploaded_images = uploaded_images - pictures.length;
        alert('ניתן להעלות עד חמש תמונות בלבד');
        return;
    }
    for(i=0; i < pictures.length; i++){
        formData.append('pictures['+i+']', pictures[i]);
    }
    if(window.FormData === undefined){
        alert('הדפדפן שאת משתמשת בו ישן מידיי, אנו ממליצים להתקין Chrome');
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/uploadPictures',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#post-upload i').removeClass('fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x').addClass('spinner');
        },
        success: function(url){
            for(i=0; i < pictures.length; i++){
                $('#post-pictures').append('<img src="' + url.pic[i] +'"/>');
            }
            $('#post-pictures').fadeIn();
            $('#post-upload i').addClass('fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x').removeClass('spinner');
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#post-upload i').addClass('fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x').removeClass('spinner');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think... its a server issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multipart/form-data as enctype and change max_post_size  and max_upload_size in php.ini greater than the size of your max file size for five files

Answer (score 1):

Basically... as far as I can tell... You are not using `multipart/form-data` content type.

So... Your browser is sending all the data as a single request.

Now... on your server ( which I assume is in php )... there should be a limit of `maximum-request-size`. And... I think it is being exceeded for 5 files.

Increase your `maximum-request-size` on your server. It should work then.

Assuming php... you have to change these particular things in your `php.ini` :

```
// Increase as per your expected file-upload size
post_max_size = 30m
// Expected input parsing time... in seconds
max_input_time = 20
// Increase as per your expected execution time of upload script... including input parsing... in seconds
max_execution_time = 30
```